# Android Studio исправление сразу в нескольких строках, как?

Tags: android-studio

Знаю есть команда, которая меняет часть строки одновременно в нескольких, не могу найти какое сочетание клавиш.

Пример:

```
private String str
private String str
private String str
private String str
```

надо поменять на

```
public String str
public String str
public String str
public String str
```

Как это сделать одновременно во всех полях?

Comment: Ctrl+F потом Ctrl+R

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это называется [мультикурсор](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html)

Держите `ALT+SHIFT` и расставляете левой кнопкой мыши курсоры во всех позициях, где надо редактировать. После чего, собственно, редактируете.

Либо ставите курсор на первую строку, жмете дважды `CTRL`(после второго раза не отпускаете) и стрелками вниз/вверх выделяете строки для редактирования.

Comment: Alt + Shift не работает как ожидается. Переключение в режим мультикурсора так же можно осуществить нажатием Alt + Shift + Insert, или более банально с контектсного меню, пункт Column Selection Mode.

Comment: @Yazon2006 только что проверил - работает. Может просто у вас Mac?

Comment: Нет, у меня Ubuntu)

Comment: @Yazon2006 Проверил в убунте. Работает.

Comment: @Roman да, действительно. Я не правильно понял смысл слов "расставляете курсоры" я пытался сделать это с помощью курсорных клавиш, а не с помощью мыши

Answer (score 2):

Очень странно, что никто не написал про

> `Alt + J`

на Udacity Google начинают уроки с этого хотекея, ну прям жизненно необходимый. Ну или когда несколько строк, без поиска по имени то конечно `Double Ctrl` + hold, UP/DOWN. Те нажимаем дважды не отпускаем и вверх или вниз.

В вашем примере очень просто делается выделяете слово private нажимаете Alt+J 3 раза пишите public Enter готово.

Ps. На Ubuntu раскладочку проверьте)

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска и замены можно воспользоваться комбинацией Ctrl+R

**UPD**

Ещё можно выделить нужный блок кода и при замене поставить галочку "In selection"

Comment: Не совсем то, нужно чтоб поменяло именно в выделенной области.

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko обновил ответ.